# sending binary files through TCP sockets c

Tags: c#, c++, c, sockets, tcp

I made a client & server that establishes a TCP connection through sockets, I'm trying to send binary data over the socket but I could only send txt or pdf files, I had no luck with exe files, I use fread and fseek to read the file and split it into a buffer. When I read the whole exe file it gets sent successfully but when I split it, it gets sent corrupted!

I read some books about sockets but I still don't know much and I have some questions.

is it okay to send the whole file in one send()?? or I should continue with sending it in small chunks?

Also, why exe files get corrupted when I send them in chunks?

Thank you!

Client Code (in c):

```
int bufSize = 10000;
int sentBytes = 0;


  FILE * pFile;
  long remainingBytes;
  char * buffer;
  size_t result;

  pFile = fopen ( "D:\\file.exe" , "rb" );
  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  remainingBytes = ftell (pFile);
  rewind (pFile);

int bufferSize = remainingBytes > bufSize ? bufSize : remainingBytes;
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*bufferSize);
send(Socket, (char*)&remainingBytes, 4, 0);

while(remainingBytes > 0)
{
    fseek (pFile , sentBytes , SEEK_SET);
    result = fread(buffer,1,bufferSize,pFile);
    if(bufferSize < remainingBytes)
    {
        send(Socket, buffer, bufferSize, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        send(Socket, buffer, remainingBytes, 0);
        bufferSize = remainingBytes;
    }
    remainingBytes -= bufferSize;
    sentBytes += bufferSize;
}
```

Server code (in c#)

```
        try
        {
            int bufferSize = 200;
            int len = 0;
            int receivedBytes = 0;
            int remainingBytes = len;
            byte[] length = new byte[4];
            //byte[] imgBuf = new byte[bufferSize];

            int current = 0;
            List<byte[]> coming = new List<byte[]>();

            sockets[number].Receive(length,4,0);

            len = BitConverter.ToInt32(length, 0);
            remainingBytes = len;

            bufferSize = len < bufferSize ? len : bufferSize;

            while(receivedBytes < len)
            {
                if (remainingBytes > bufferSize)
                {
                    coming.Add(new byte[bufferSize]);
                    //imgBuf = new byte[bufferSize];
                    sockets[number].Receive(coming[current], bufferSize, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    coming.Add(new byte[remainingBytes]);
                    //imgBuf = new byte[remainingBytes];
                    sockets[number].Receive(coming[current], remainingBytes, 0);
                    bufferSize = remainingBytes;
                }
                remainingBytes -= bufferSize;
                receivedBytes += bufferSize;
                current++;
                //Array.Clear(imgBuf, 0, imgBuf.Length);
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\receivedFile.exe",FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                    foreach (byte[] buffer in coming)
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(buffer);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { this.setText(ex.Message, textBox2); }
```

Edit: Thanks for the help, I got it working :)

```
        try
        {
            int bufferSize = 1024 * 100;
            int len = 0;
            int receivedBytes = 0;
            int remainingBytes = len;
            int reached = 0;

            byte[] length = new byte[4];
            byte[] imgBuf = new byte[bufferSize];

            int current = 0;
            sockets[number].Receive(length,4,0);

            len = BitConverter.ToInt32(length, 0);
            remainingBytes = len;

            bufferSize = len < bufferSize ? len : bufferSize;
            imgBuf = new byte[len];

            while (reached < len)
            {
                reached += sockets[number].Receive(imgBuf, receivedBytes, remainingBytes, 0);
                remainingBytes = len - reached;
                receivedBytes = reached;
                current++;
                //Array.Clear(imgBuf, 0, imgBuf.Length);
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\putty.exe",FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                        binaryWriter.Write(imgBuf);
                }
            }
            Array.Clear(imgBuf, 0, imgBuf.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { this.setText(ex.Message, textBox2); }
```

Comment: If you're transferring a whole file from a filesystem, you should probably use [`TransmitFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565(VS.85).aspx) (if on Windows), or [`sendfile()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) (if on Unix)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I mentioned, I get no problems at all when I send the whole file. The problem only occurs when I try to send it in chunks.

Comment: what I was trying to say is, you shouldn't send a file from the disk by buffering it in memory to begin with for performance reasons, whether it's in chunks or not - using one of those functions is more efficient.

Comment: tried it and no luck! still the same problem, exe files are corrupted while txt's and other types not!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't check how many bytes you actually received in `sockets[number].Receive(coming[current], bufferSize, 0);` . It doesn't have to be equal to the buffer size you have declared.
Additionaly, as said in comments, keeping whole file in memory is not a good idea.

Comment: i don't know how useful would this be, but this always receives the same length as "bufferSize" .

I edited this line to
  bytesReceived = sockets[number].Receive(coming[current], bufferSize, 0);

Comment: It is hard to get it in debug mode, just add an exception for  bytesReceived!=coming[current].Length and run your code

Comment: I found out what was wrong finally,
I had to use the overload o function receive

    bytess = sockets[number].Receive(imgBuf,receivedBytes , bufferSize, 0);

instead of creating a list of bytes and add a new byte array with each receive, I made one byte array with the message length and appended all requests to it

Comment: @Adel Ali It's not only useful to check the received length, and handle only the number of bytes Receive() returns (as opposed to just assuming the whole buffer got filled up). It is absolutely necessary. Maybe you can't reproduce a case in your test environment with the given input/output where this happens, but some day it will.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to checking the number of bytes received, you need to check the number of bytes sent by each send call -- if your TCP transmit window fills up, a send call might send less data than you requested, in which case the you'll need to resend the unsent data.

In general, you ALWAYS need to check the return value of your system calls to check for the all the various odd corner cases that can occur.  Read the man pages for send(2) and recv(2) for a full list of everything that can happen.